# Drupal 7 Admin Overlay positioned to high

Tags: drupal-7

This is a problem that seems to have occurred for no reason. Everything was working fine, and now all of a sudden the overlay iframe for the admin interface renders too high so that any tabs are rendered underneath the toolbar. I hadn't edited any css or html so I don't see how I could have done this. Has anyone seen this happen, and how did they fix it? I'm attaching two images. One shows the site as it is (incorrectly). The other shows another similar site that is functioning correctly. Also, notice on the incorrect display, somehow the toolbar is showing OVER the browser scrollbar.

[image: Incorrect Display]

[image: Correct Display]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that I was swapping in JQuery 1.8.3 with hook_js_alter. This has a known problem causing this exact issue. I didn't need a later version of JQuery after all so I removed that, and it fixed the problem.

Comment: I saw the same issue using the jQuery Update module. jQuery v1.7 does not cause the problem. jQuery v1.8 does.